# Groovy version mismatch running spock test in Gradle project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy, gradle, spock, eclipse-kepler

I have a Groovy and Gradle project in Eclipse Kepler with a few classes and a single Spock spec.  I can run the Gradle build from the shell, and it works fine, including the Spock spec.

I now wanted to try running the Spock spec in Eclipse, either in the debugger or not.  When I run it, I see the following:

```
Conflicting module versions. Module [groovy-all is loaded in version 2.3.9 and
you are trying to load version 2.3.10
```

Here is my "dependencies" block from build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile localGroovy()
    compile gradleApi()
    compile "org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-parser-impl:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT"
    testCompile("org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.3") {
        exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy"
    }
}
```

I can see in the Project Explorer that my Gradle dependencies has groovy-all-2.3.9.jar and my Groovy dependencies has groovy-all-2.3.10.jar.

This is a bit of a mess.  Can I safely edit my Groovy dependencies of the project and change the jar to the 2.3.9 version?

**Update**:

Here is what "groovy dependencies" from the command line says.  This is irrelevant to what Eclipse is using.

```
:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

archives - Configuration for archive artifacts.
No dependencies

compile - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.9
\--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-parser-impl:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-common:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
 |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2
 |    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:concepts:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 |    \--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:object-cache-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 |         +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:concepts:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 |         +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2
 |         \--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
 +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-model-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 |    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:object-cache-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT (*)
 |    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:util:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 |    |    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:concepts:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 |    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.3
 |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2
 |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
 |    |    \--- com.github.romix:java-concurrent-hash-trie-map:0.2.23
 |    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-common:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT (*)
 |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
 |    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.3
 +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-parser-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 |    \--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-model-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT (*)
 +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-model-util:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 |    \--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-model-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT (*)
 +--- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.0
 |    \--- org.abego.treelayout:org.abego.treelayout.core:1.0.1
 +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
 +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:concepts:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
 \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.3

default - Configuration for default artifacts.
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.9
\--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-parser-impl:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-common:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
 |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2
 |    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:concepts:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 |    \--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:object-cache-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 |         +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:concepts:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 |         +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2
 |         \--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
 +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-model-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 |    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:object-cache-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT (*)
 |    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:util:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 |    |    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:concepts:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 |    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.3
 |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2
 |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
 |    |    \--- com.github.romix:java-concurrent-hash-trie-map:0.2.23
 |    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-common:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT (*)
 |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
 |    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.3
 +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-parser-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 |    \--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-model-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT (*)
 +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-model-util:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 |    \--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-model-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT (*)
 +--- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.0
 |    \--- org.abego.treelayout:org.abego.treelayout.core:1.0.1
 +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
 +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:concepts:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
 \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.3

runtime - Runtime classpath for source set 'main'.
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.9
\--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-parser-impl:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-common:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
 |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2
 |    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:concepts:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 |    \--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:object-cache-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 |         +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:concepts:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 |         +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2
 |         \--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
 +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-model-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 |    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:object-cache-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT (*)
 |    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:util:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 |    |    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:concepts:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 |    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.3
 |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2
 |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
 |    |    \--- com.github.romix:java-concurrent-hash-trie-map:0.2.23
 |    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-common:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT (*)
 |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
 |    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.3
 +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-parser-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 |    \--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-model-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT (*)
 +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-model-util:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 |    \--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-model-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT (*)
 +--- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.0
 |    \--- org.abego.treelayout:org.abego.treelayout.core:1.0.1
 +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
 +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:concepts:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
 +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
 \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.3

testCompile - Compile classpath for source set 'test'.
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.9
+--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-parser-impl:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
|    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-common:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2
|    |    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:concepts:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
|    |    \--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:object-cache-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
|    |         +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:concepts:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
|    |         +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2
|    |         \--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
|    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-model-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
|    |    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:object-cache-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT (*)
|    |    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:util:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
|    |    |    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:concepts:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
|    |    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.3
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
|    |    |    \--- com.github.romix:java-concurrent-hash-trie-map:0.2.23
|    |    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-common:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
|    |    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.3
|    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-parser-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
|    |    \--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-model-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT (*)
|    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-model-util:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
|    |    \--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-model-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT (*)
|    +--- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.0
|    |    \--- org.abego.treelayout:org.abego.treelayout.core:1.0.1
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
|    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:concepts:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
|    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
|    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.3
\--- org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.3
 \--- junit:junit:4.12
      \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

testRuntime - Runtime classpath for source set 'test'.
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.9
+--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-parser-impl:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
|    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-common:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2
|    |    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:concepts:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
|    |    \--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:object-cache-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
|    |         +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:concepts:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
|    |         +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2
|    |         \--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
|    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-model-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
|    |    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:object-cache-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT (*)
|    |    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:util:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
|    |    |    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:concepts:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
|    |    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.3
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
|    |    |    \--- com.github.romix:java-concurrent-hash-trie-map:0.2.23
|    |    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-common:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
|    |    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.3
|    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-parser-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
|    |    \--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-model-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT (*)
|    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-model-util:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
|    |    \--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:yang-model-api:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT (*)
|    +--- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.0
|    |    \--- org.abego.treelayout:org.abego.treelayout.core:1.0.1
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0
|    +--- org.opendaylight.yangtools:concepts:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT
|    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.4
|    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.3
\--- org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.3
 \--- junit:junit:4.12
      \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.041 secs
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using kepler and gradle each one places its groovy module on the classpath. Lets not use kepler's one: 
[image]

Comment: Bingo! I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the dependency below instead of `localGroovy()`, in order to avoid troubles with team members. Let the dependency management work to gradle

```
compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.9"
```

**Edit 01**
Check this link, in order to switch de groovy version
http://groovy.codehaus.org/Compiler+Switching+within+Groovy-Eclipse

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this made no difference. The Groovy dependencies still specify 2.3.10, and running the test gets the same error.

Comment: which gradle version are you using?

Comment: Can you run gradle dependencies and attach the log in your question, please?

Comment: Fine, but you're going down the wrong path. The problem is not my gradle configuration. Gradle is trying to use Groovy 2.3.9, but the Eclipse Groovy plugin is trying to use Groovy 2.3.10.

Comment: Ok, I got. This link will help to switch the groovy version in eclipse http://groovy.codehaus.org/Compiler+Switching+within+Groovy-Eclipse